# Kali linux 2018.4 seems to be missing with me

Tags: kali-linux

I installed Kali Linux 2018.4 today. Its not the first time to install a Kali Linux but had to do it because I wanted to upgrade. Anyway, after I burnt the Kali Linux to my CD-DVD disk and I booted up to it. From that point everything was different and looks new for me. I went to advanced options and did install in graphical mode. After I went through the normal installation I am used to do successfully. There was some changes it didn't really matter. After the installation is finished and booted up to Kali Linux there was this weird screen where you have to login through commands and I logged in but the terminal was still open with no GUI.

I did a little research and typed `startx` and the Kali Linux opened.

Now, there was WiFi setting, there was no the programs var on the center mid where you open the terminal and other stuff and so many different things
I went to Youtube to check and the 2018.4 and how it looks. It looked completely normal for me!

I did the sudo update commands and the others and rebooted and now the grub loader didn't work instead it gives to my windows 10.. I think its because if the legacy mode was enabled and out it back to UEFI and deleted the Kali Linux partitions to try again later.

I am 100 percent sure I downloaded the right copy.. Could it wasn't burnt correctly??

Answer (score 0):

*Note: Assuming question is "Could Kali linux have not burned correctly to CD-DVD?"*

No, the issue is not with integrity of burned copy.

When you installed, maybe you messed up your old Kali install (need to chroot first from livecd image?)

Other possibility are bad boot loader config or messed up partition mount points.